# symfony2/twig: How to simulate the old slots of symfony1 in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig

I just don't want to show the login form of the layout in the main login page..

I tried to set a variable in the login child template (`{% set layout_login = false %}`) and checking its value in the layout, but i needed to set also the variable in the layout (`{% set layout_login = true %}`), and it always catches the value of the variable set in the layout (true)....

And tried also setting a variable in the controller, but there isn't anything like `isset()` in twig...

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just define a block in your main layout?

```
{% block loginForm %}
    <form />
{% endblock %}
```

And overload it in your login template:

```
{% block loginForm %}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to isset() is defined.

I wrote st like this:

```
{% if layout_login is not defined %}

    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

        <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

        <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
        <label for="remember_me">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>

        <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
    </form>

{% endif %}
```